# What is the relationship between $\partial_x^2\frac1r$ and $\delta^3(r)$?

Tags: differentiation, mathematics, dirac-delta-distributions

We have the equation
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2\frac1r=-4\pi\delta^3(r).
\end{equation}
I first encountered this equation in electrodynamics. So what is $\partial_x^2\frac1r$ then? It looks like the result is
\begin{equation}
\partial_x^2\frac1r=\frac{2x^2-y^2-z^2}{r^5}, \qquad r\neq 0.
\end{equation}
But this leads to $$\nabla^2\frac1r=(\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2+\partial_z^2)\frac1r=0, \qquad r\neq 0,$$ which seems to contradicts $\nabla^2\frac1r=-4\pi\delta^3(r)$. So what is the relationship between $\partial_x^2\frac1r$ and $\delta^3(r)$?

Comment: That result holds only for $r\neq 0$, right? Via the Divergence theorem, what happens when you integrate $\nabla^2(1/r)$ over a volume (e.g. a ball, for simplicity) containing the origin?

Comment: Possible duplicate on Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3525923/11127

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to belong on [math.se]